# Mean-center continuous predictors for GLMMs?

Tags: distributions, mixed-model, glmm

I have a dataset with a non-negative, right-skewed response variable and at least one non-negative, right-skewed predictor. Given the non-Gaussian, non-negative distribution of the predictor variable, it is my understanding that I should fit GLMMs with a negative binomial linking function. I accomplish this with `glmmTMB::glmmTMB, family="nbinom1."`

Do I need to mean-center the response and/or predictor variables as I normally would for regular LMM? If so, how do I do this without generating negative data (thereby invalidating my `GLMMtmb` fit)?

Comment: Negative binomial is a family, not a link. Whether a negative binomial is a good idea for your data is neither implied nor refuted by the information you give, as non-negative and right skewed could imply other models too. You can do to your predictors whatever you like, but the response should be left as it came, and not mean-centered. I guess you are alluding to a R function; whether that is true or false it's a good idea to name the statistical program or environment you are using.

Comment: I have no idea whether the code requires `GLMMtmb` or `glmmTMB` but I would be surprised if either were allowed.

Comment: If you are asking about how to do this in R, then the question is off topic. But it seems like you are asking a statistical question and that the use of R is incidental. If you lessen the emphasis on R, then the question will be on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative binomial distribution is used for over-dispersed count data. If your response variable is continuous, then the negative binomial would perhaps not be an appropriate model. In this case, you could consider a Gamma distribution or if you also have an upper bound in your outcome a Beta distribution.

Regarding centering your predictors, this is not strictly necessary but sometimes it improves the convergence of the optimization algorithm. Centering of your outcome would not be required.